# How to delay for loop by 1 second in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new at javascript. I want to create a for loop that iterate after 1 second.

```
for(sec=60;sec>0; sec--){
    document.write(sec);    
}
```

When i use above code, for loop print everything immediately.I want that for loop executes every 1 second. I know it can be done by using `setInterval();` function but i don't know how to do it exactly. Please suggest me best solution how to do.

Comment: Then why won't you use `setInterval`?

Comment: i don't know how to use it. Please tell me

Comment: setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);

Comment: Please add in my code, how to do it. Please sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to run at every 1 second, and then use `clearInterval` to prevent any further executions once the count is 60.

```js
var count = 1;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  
  console.log("Count: " + count);
  
  if(count == 60)
  {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  else 
  {
    count++;
  }
},1000);
```

Comment: can't it be done in for loop?

Comment: Why do you need a for loop now?